# Как правильно деструктурировать сложный объект

Tags: javascript

```
function calculateMeanTemperature(forecast) {
  const todayLow = forecast.today.low;
  const todayHigh = forecast.today.high;
  const tomorrowLow = forecast.tomorrow.low;
  const tomorrowHigh = forecast.tomorrow.high;

  // Change code above this line
  return (todayLow + todayHigh + tomorrowLow + tomorrowHigh) / 4;
}
```

Функция calculateMeanTemperature(forecast) принимает один параметр forecast – объект температур на два дня следующего формата.

```
{
  today: { low: 10, high: 20 },
  tomorrow: { low: 20, high: 30 }
}
```

Замени объявления переменных todayLow, todayHigh, tomorrowLow и tomorrowHigh одной операцией деструктуризации свойств объекта forecast.

Условия:

- Объявленная функция `calculateMeanTemperature(forecast)`
- В теле функции используется деструктуризация объекта
- В теле функции объявлена ​​переменная `todayHigh` с помощью деструктуризации
- В теле функции объявлена ​​переменная `todayLow` с помощью деструктуризации
- В теле функции объявлена ​​переменная `tomorrowLow` посредством деструктуризации
- В теле функции объявлена ​​переменная `tomorrowHigh` с помощью деструктуризации

Тесты:

- Вызов `calculateMeanTemperature({ today: {low: 28, high: 32}, tomorrow: {low: 25, high: 29} })` возвращает `28.5`
- Вызов `calculateMeanTemperature({ today: {low: 37, high: 40}, tomorrow: {low: 33, high: 38} })` возвращает `37`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну тут не один способ деструктуризации можно применить:

1. Самый простой и очевидный - просто перечисляем какой переменной что достанется:

   ```js
   const data = {
     today: { low: 10, high: 20 },
     tomorrow: { low: 20, high: 30 }
   };

   function calculateMeanTemperature(forecast) {
     const [
       todayLow,
       todayHigh,
       tomorrowLow,
       tomorrowHigh
     ] = [
       forecast.today.low,
       forecast.today.high,
       forecast.tomorrow.low,
       forecast.tomorrow.high,
     ]

     // Change code above this line
     return (todayLow + todayHigh + tomorrowLow + tomorrowHigh) / 4;
   }

   console.log(calculateMeanTemperature(data));
   ```
2. Деструктурировать в 2 этапа. Сначала для `today`, а потом для `tomorrow`

   ```js
   const data = {
     today: { low: 10, high: 20 },
     tomorrow: { low: 20, high: 30 }
   };

   function calculateMeanTemperature(forecast) {
     const {low: todayLow, high: todayHigh} = forecast.today;
     const {low: tomorrowLow, high: tomorrowHigh} = forecast.tomorrow;

     // Change code above this line
     return (todayLow + todayHigh + tomorrowLow + tomorrowHigh) / 4;
   }

   console.log(calculateMeanTemperature(data));
   ```
3. Тоже самое что и во втором, только `today` и `tomorrow` деструктруируем отдельно:

   ```js
   const data = {
     today: { low: 10, high: 20 },
     tomorrow: { low: 20, high: 30 }
   };

   function calculateMeanTemperature(forecast) {
     const {today, tomorrow} = forecast;
     const {low: todayLow, high: todayHigh} = today;
     const {low: tomorrowLow, high: tomorrowHigh} = tomorrow;

     // Change code above this line
     return (todayLow + todayHigh + tomorrowLow + tomorrowHigh) / 4;
   }

   console.log(calculateMeanTemperature(data));
   ```
4. Почти как первый, в том плане, что опять перечисляем по одному для всех, но уже деструктурируем как объект:

   ```js
   const data = {
     today: { low: 10, high: 20 },
     tomorrow: { low: 20, high: 30 }
   };

   function calculateMeanTemperature(forecast) {
     const {
       today: {low: todayLow, high: todayHigh},
       tomorrow: {low: tomorrowLow, high: tomorrowHigh}
     } = forecast;

     // Change code above this line
     return (todayLow + todayHigh + tomorrowLow + tomorrowHigh) / 4;
   }

   console.log(calculateMeanTemperature(data));
   ```

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: @protebe Если ответ вам помог, то не забудьте пожалуйста его принять нажав на галочку слева от ответа :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculateMeanTemperature(forecast) {
 const{
  today: {low:todayLow, high: todayHigh},
  tomorrow: {low:tomorrowLow, high: tomorrowHigh
 }} = forecast;

  // Change code above this line
  return (todayLow + todayHigh + tomorrowLow + tomorrowHigh) / 4;
}
```